# Join two tables on multiple columns without duplicate rows

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables:

Table A:

- id

Table B:

- id1
- id2
- ... (lots of other columns)

I want to get all the rows in B where either B.id1 or B.id2 is A.id (all A.id are distinct. This isn't the case for B).

I've tried the query:

```
create table C as
select B.*
from B 
join A on (A.id = B.id1 or A.id = B.id2);
```

This works great except it duplicates rows where id1 and id2 are both in id. A is a relatively small table (around 5000 rows) whereas B is quite large (around 1 billion rows).

Solutions that I've thought of involve grouping by the columns of B so it eliminates distinct rows, collect the ids of A into an array and searching for id1 and id2 in the array, and using 2 separate queries which search for id1 and id2 respectively and then union the two tables. These all seem quite inefficient especially considering the size of the tables. Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using `select distinct`?

Comment: It would be too slow considering the size of my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id1) or
      exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id2);
```

In most databases, this would be the most efficient method for this type of logic.  I'm not 100% sure that this is true in Hive, but it is definitely worth a try.

An alternative approach would be `left join`s:

```
select b.*
from b left join
     a a1
     on b.id1 = a1.id left join
     a a2
     on b.id2 = a2.id
where a1.id is not null or a2.id is not null;
```

This might have better performance in Hive, if the `exists` does not have good optimization.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think the first will work since hive doesn't support correlated subqueries, but the alternative looks perfect. I didn't even consider using left joins but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @TheSlimyDog . . . Hive does support correlated subqueries with `EXISTS` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries), although older versions probably do not.

Comment: I tried it out and the first version didn't work. I get the error: 
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 4:6 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'id2': Only 1 SubQuery expression is supported.
It seems to work if I only have one expression but both doesn't.